# "Warning: Issue establishing a database connection!" but the connection string is correct

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, .net, web-config

I am migrating a .NET application from one server to another. All I did was zip and move the compiled project folder from one server to another. Then I edited the connection string with correct server name, username and password. 
On the back end I tested the username and password and everything works fine. Also check the permissions. Nothing is wrong. But the site login is still not working and is throwing `Warning: Issue establishing a database connection!` error when I enter username/password and hit login. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any weird characters in your password that need escaping in your config file? Not that I want to know what characters you have in your password, of course.

Comment: no. Because the same web config file is used in the other server(source server) and the application works perfectly fine there :(